# Namespace related error on creating SOAP Request

Tags: java, web-services, dom, xml-namespaces

My attempt is to create multiple soap messages from the following SOAPBody content[just a sample one, no the actual]. There will be seperate requests for each EmpId.

```
<Request>
  <EMPId>?</EMPId>
</Request>
```

I use the following code to convert the above request string to a Document Object.

```
DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = parser.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes())));
```

Once i have the document, i can create SOAPBody by substituting the EMPId values.

Now i have to creare individual SOAPMessages for each SOAPBody created.

For that I use the following code.

```
private static String cretaeSOAPMessage(Document soapBodyDoc, String serverURI, String soapAction){
    String soapMsg = null;

    try {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("v1",serverURI);

        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();

        soapBodyDoc.setPrefix("v1");
        soapBody.addDocument(soapBodyDoc);

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + soapAction);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            soapMessage.writeTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        soapMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());

    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return soapMsg;
}
```

But I am getting the following error on executing the line with content '**soapBodyDoc.setPrefix("v1");**'

> Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An
>   attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is
>   incorrect with regard to namespaces.

I tried to add the namespace prefic where i create the SOAPBody, even that dint worked out.
How can i avoid this error and add namespace prefix to the SOAPBody?

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved. 
Namespace declaration is removed from envelope and added to body.

```
   MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();


    soapBody.addDocument(soapBodyDoc);
    **soapBody.addNamespaceDeclaration("", serverURI);**
```

Prefix is removed as the original does not have any prefix.